# abbreviation for number neutral?

Tags: grammar

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this..

But when identifying pronouns, they are often given codes

1ms = 1st person masculine singular

and if a language, e.g. english and many others, don't specify gender in the first person, then C is (common?) gender..

1cs = (I guess) 1st person ("common?") singular

So "I" or "me" in English is given the pronoun abbreviation code 1cs

What about though, if the third letter in the abbreviation (the gender), is "common"? e.g. in English, in the second person "You" can be male or female, singular or plural.  It's like 2cc (though i've not seen the abbreviation 2cc)   What is the correct abbreviation to describe that neutral gender and neutral number?

Comment: Where did you get the **1ms** notation from? I'm not familiar with it, and Google Books has no instances of those three characters in close proximity to either **1st** or **first person masculine singular**. But you must have got it from *somewhere, so presumably that's the place to look for other forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _1ms_, _1fs_, _1mpl_, _1fpl_, etc., are fairly common ways to write this. Sometimes reversed as _1sm/1sf/1plm/1plf_, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah, was a book a while back on hebrew, but the pronoun abbreviations would apply to english too and I thought the abbreviations might be standard in english since they are english abbreviations  http://biblicalhebrewmadeeasy.weebly.com/uploads/1/9/6/9/1969508/1096371.jpg   should apply to English too e.g. 1cs(I/me) 1cp(we/us)  Though it had nothing on neutral number.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet what about  neutral number and neutral gender?

Comment: they seem to be morphology codes/abbreviations https://wiki.logos.com/morphology_codes

Answer (score 1):

There is a misconception in the basis of your question here: *common gender* is not the same as not specifying gender. The common gender is an actual gender, used in some languages (Danish, Swedish, Norwegian Bokmål, Hittite, etc.). I would *not* advise using that to refer to non-gendered forms.

In languages (or pronouns, or any other context) that does not specify gender at all, the most common practice is to simply *leave out the gender-designating letter altogether*. So where *1ms* is ‘first person singular, masculine’, the most common way of writing ‘first person singular, any gender’ is simply **1s**.

The same logic is sometimes applied to number as well; for example, the Lithuanian verb is always the same in the third person, whether singular or plural, and this is often noted as simply **3**, with no extra letters at all. The same can be done for *you* in English.

If you wish to be more specific and reduce the risk of misunderstanding—a single number in running text is not necessarily very clear—you can include all the possible values instead of leaving them all out. In that way, the Lithuanian verb forms would be **3spl** (or **3s/pl** for enhanced readability), and *you* in English is **2splmf** (or **2s/pl-m/f** for readability). This is the approach usually taken when a particular form is relevant to multiple (but not all) cases in a given paradigm, like the Sanskrit ending *-bhyām*, which is **idadu** (instrumental, dative, and ablative dual).

Comment: what is the difference between common gender, and  gender not specified? like "you" in english is that common gender  or gender not specified?

Comment: Common (or commune) gender is an actual gender, like masculine and feminine. English has no grammatical gender, so _you_ (and everything else, except perhaps _he_ and _she_.

Comment: I'm asking if you can explain the difference between an actual common gender, and no gender.

Comment: @barlop: I'd have thought "singular **they**" in English represents an "actual" common gender use, where **it** implies "**no** gender". But IANAL (Linguist, in this case).

Comment: @barlop The difference is the same as the difference between masculine and no gender, for example. Pronouns are a bit of a special case, because they can refer to both grammatical and physical gender, not always overlapping. The Scandinavian languages, for instance, have deictic/personal pronouns for the third person singular for both physical sexes (e.g., Danish _han_ ‘he’, _hun_ ‘she’) as well as for both grammatical genders (e.g., Danish _den_ ‘it [common]’, _det_ ‘it [neuter]’). There is no 3s pronoun that does not encode information about gender, but one that encodes common gender.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah you're right..it seems the correct terms are common gender, vs neuter gender  http://www.english-for-students.com/Common-Gender.html Common Gender : A noun denotes either a male or a female sex is called Common Gender. 


Neuter Gender : A noun that denotes a lifeless thing is called Neuter Gender. Neuter means neither male nor female.

Comment: also here http://www.english-language-grammar-guide.com/grammatical-gender.html   But considering that i'm talking about 1st person, 2nd person, 3rd person..   - pronouns preceding verbs,  and i'm not talking about tables and chairs so i'm not talking about things of neuter gender.. The term "common" seems to be correct. so You is common gender. It's not that you doesn't have a gender, it's that it can be either male or female, so it's common gender not neuter gender.

Comment: So where you write "The common gender is an actual gender, used in some languages (Danish, Swedish, Norwegian Bokmål, Hittite, etc.). I would not advise using that to refer to non-gendered forms."  <--  I don't see what you mean. You are suggesting that English doesn't have common and neuter, but it does.. boy is gendered, landlord, stag.. they are gendered.  Table,chair, are neuter.  And I am talking about the gendered.. specifically, the common.  e.g. "You"

Comment: @barlop No, those English words are not gendered. They refer to things that have actual, physical sex, but that is not gender. In Danish, ‘table’ and ‘house’ are neuter, while ‘chair’ and ‘cottage’ are common gender—they are declined in different ways and use different articles, just like masculine and feminine nouns in French, for instance. Gender is a purely grammatical notion that is (at least partly) orthogonal to sex; cf. how German _Mädchen_ ‘girl’ is neuter and Irish _cailín_ ‘girl’ is masculine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think even if the inflection or declination of the word is the same, the pronouns can still differ and in old english the words were inflected/declined so are still considered masculine or feminine. And looking at  a book I have p70 of "english grammar to ace biblical hebrew" by miles van pelt  http://i.imgur.com/fCQcJnB.png    he says he got this his english teacher.  And you see he 1cs 2cs 1cp 2cp 3cp  despite the fact that the word is the same "ran" no different inflections. He labelled them based on pronoun. And notice he did a 3ns for "It". So "common" and "neuter"